# Unable to take backup by Cassy

Tags: scalardb

I have been trying to take backup using Cassy, but I could only get metadata backup.
It seems that there's no error-logs on Cassy and the status is "STARTED" on Cassy's BackupList.

Below is the steps I tried for deployment. Is there any lacking steps or something should be correct?

First, I created scalar DL, cassandra and envoy with git clone from below.

`git clone https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalar-samples.git`

I've chencked that it works and I can execute contract correctly.

Then I added Cassy container as below.

1. Add ssh to cassandra nodes.
2. Change commitlog_sync from periodic to batch.
3. Git clone from below
   git clone https://github.com/scalar-labs/cassy
4. Edit cassy.properties file to add S3 infomation and other paths.
5. Create container using cloned Dockerfile.
   cassy/build/docker/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure about the environment you are working on.
Is Cassy master in your localhost and other components like Cassandra are in Docker ?
If that is the case, then I doubt that Cassy can connect Cassandra via JMX.

BTW, are there any logs in /var/log/scalar ?

Answer (score 0):

I deployed all nodes on one docker EC2.
Cassandra and Cassy can connect using docker local network.
Also I checked if Cassandra is listening JMX.
172.21.0.2 is the cassandra container's docker network IP.

```
# netstat -tln
 Active Internet connections (only servers)
 Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9042            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
 tcp        0      0 172.21.0.2:7000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:46715        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7199            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

If I deploy cassy using "./gradlew installDist", I can get /var/log/scalar/cassy.log.
It shows only a below log.

```
 2020-07-22 05:35:21.641 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  c.s.c.transferer.AwsS3FileUploader - Uploading /tmp/cassy.db.dump
```

But If I changed to deploy cassy using "./gradlew docker", there is no such log file on cassy container.

Comment: Cassy docker container logs to STDOUT based on the best practice so can you see something if you do `docker logs` ?

Comment: I checked Cassy's docker logs, it shows only below.

23:58:19.491 [main] INFO  com.scalar.cassy.server.CassyServer - Server started, listening on 20051
00:01:27.358 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  c.s.c.transferer.AwsS3FileUploader - Uploading /tmp/cassy.db.dump

Comment: Can Cassy master do ssh to C* nodes with a specified private key ?

Comment: In my understanding, Cassy container cannot do ssh but if it is possible would you mind to tell me how to do it?
I checked that I can do ssh from Docker instance to Cassandra container using ssh private key which I imported to the Cassy container.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I've ever tried such case where everything is working in Docker. Let me check when I get a chance.
If you can, can you also try scalar-terraform ? It uses Docker for Cassy master and it can properly take backups.

Comment: Also, there is [cassy] tag. so please use it when you ask about cassy.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cassy

Comment: We've already confirmed it does work on scalar-terraform, but just interested making all scalarDLT containers working in one docker host. It's not urgent but we would appreciate if you could check and give us any advice when you are available.
I will post with cassy tag from next time, thank you for the info.

Comment: We were able to reproduce it and fixed it in the current master of scalar-samples.
Please try it again.

The cause is `_` used in the hostname in scalar-samples that makes the SSH library fails since probably it is invalid in terms of  RFC 822.